# Null points from drilldown remain on screen on subsequent drilldown of a different location

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, highmaps, highcharts-ng

I have reproduced my issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/1bf4ob05/4/

And here is the issue on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6308

Is there some configuration that needs to be passed. It seems to happen when you pass data and mapData separately (see the fiddle or below) and not all of the drilldown data points have values. The null points from one drilldown still show on the drilldown of the second.

```
mapData : myMapData,
data : myMockData,
```

Do I need to do some sort of clear or something in my drilldown?

Comment: I cannot see that the null points remains after drilldown. New null points are shown for a specific state - do you want to disable null points after drilldown? If so, you can set allAreas to false on drilldown event for a drilldown series - http://jsfiddle.net/1bf4ob05/5/

Comment: I do not want to set all areas to false because then they do not draw. Please look at the two links provided above and you will see the null points from california show up on drilldown of NY and vice versa.

Comment: Still, I cannot reproduce it. What OS/browser do you use? Why do you tag the question as highcharts-ng and reactjs?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1bf4ob05/4/ click CA, then drill back up. Click NY

Comment: Chrome and 10.11.6

Answer (score 0):

The problem you experience here with points "reoccuring" on new dropdowns is because you are using a single array for your data used in several dropdowns. You have:

```
 var myMockData = [
    {
        "hc-key": "us-ca-075",
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "us-ny-045",
        "value": 40,
    },
    // ...
];
```

This array is modified when you use `mapData` and `data` in a merge operation based on the `'hc-key'`. This messes it up for use in future dropdowns. Print out `myMockData` after a dropdown to see how it looks.

Instead you could use separate arrays for each new dropdown, for example like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1bf4ob05/6/)):

```
myMockData = {
    'California': [
        {
            "hc-key": "us-ca-075",
            "value": 10
        },
        // ...
    ],
    'New York': [
        {
            "hc-key": "us-ny-045",
            "value": 40,
        },
        // ...
    ]
};
```

And change your `addSeriesAsDrilldown` to look like:

```
chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
    name: e.point.name,
    mapData:myMapData,
    data:myMockData[e.point.name],
    // ...
});
```